# WebViewでvisitedを保持する方法

Tags: android, webview

androidのwebviewでも普通にa:visitedなどで移動したリンクを表示できますが、
アプリを再起動するとリセットされてしまいます。
これを保持できないでしょうか？

Comment: 以前調べた限りでは、APIとして保持する手段はないという結論でした。`WebViewClient`の`doUpdateVisitedHistory()`と`WebChromeClient`の`getVisitedHistory()`を用いて独自に履歴を管理すれば実現可能なのではないか、という推測があるのですが検証する機会がないのでコメントとして残してみます。

Comment: http://dayafterneet.blogspot.jp/2011/08/androidwebview_23.html?m=1にある、'getAppCacheEnabled'とかどうでしょう。cssセレクタのキャッシュをストアしてくれます。それとも勘違いで単に履歴を保存したかったら、http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487052/can-a-webviews-history-be-permanently-storedにあるメソッドで取得したリストをdbに突っ込めばいけるはず。。。蛇の道は蛇で、逆に消せないよ！という人の質問http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992816/how-to-clear-the-css-visited-history-of-an-android-webviewにヒントがあるのかもしれません。

Comment: @quesera2 試しにやってみましたが、doUpdateVisitedHistory()でurlを指定しても、その結果がcssのvisitedに反映はされないようです。履歴をファイルに保持して、履歴にあるリンクに対してjsでタグを付けるという方法はあるのですが、パフォーマンスに不安があり、実装が汚くなるなと・・・

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebChromeClient の [getVisitedHistory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#getVisitedHistory(android.webkit.ValueCallback<java.lang.String[]>)) をオーバーライドすることで実装できます。

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    @Override
    public void getVisitedHistory(final ValueCallback<String[]> callback) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]>() {

            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // この例では単に文字列の配列を返しているだけですが、実際は履歴を
                // 保存しておいたデータベースなどから読み込むようにしてください
                return new String[] {"http://www.google.co.jp"};
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String[] urls) {
                callback.onReceiveValue(urls);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
});
```

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます、